# Converting int to float?

Tags: c++

Whenever I try to compile I get

24 [Warning] converting to `int` from `float`

83 [Warning] converting to `int` from `float`

```
int a , b = 8;
float c = 5.2;
float d = 8E3;
a = static_cast<float>(b) * c; // 24
cout << a << "\n";
cout << d << "\n";


int x, y, answer;
x = 7;
y = 9;
answer = 5;
answer *= (x + y);
cout << answer << "\n";


answer *= x + y;
cout << answer << "\n";


float m = 33.97;
answer += (x + y + m); // 83
cout << answer << "\n";
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `a` is an int, `b*c` is a float.

Comment: You don't need to cast integers to float, as no precision will be lost that conversion can be done automatically by the compiler.

Answer (score 5):

```
a = static_cast<float>(b) * c;
```

`a` is an `int`, and the right-hand side of the equation is the multiplication of two `floats`, which will result in an intermediate `float` value, which is then implicitly casted to an `int`, causing the warning you are seeing.

Also:

```
answer += (x + y + m);
```

`answer` is an `int` type, and so are `x` and `y`, but `m` is `float`, again causing the intermediate result of the right-hand side to be a `float`.

These conversions will cause truncation of the fractional values of the `float` results.  You can get rid of the warnings by explicitly casting to an `int`:

```
a = static_cast<int>(static_cast<float>(b) * c);
answer += static_cast<int>(x + y + m);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be about conversion from float to int, not from int to float.

Basically you are doing nothing wrong. It is only a warning, as the value will be truncated (and maybe you don't expect that). To tell the compiler that you really want to get an int out of a float, you can make the cast explicit, like this:

```
a = static_cast<int>(static_cast<float>(b) * c);
```

Then it will not warn you anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Well you're just getting a warning since the compiler is changing a floating-point value to an integer, thus truncating the result.

```
int a;
float f = 3.2;
a = f; // a is 3, a trunctated 3.2
```